# iOS - Accessing the name of IBOutlet

Tags: view, subview, iboutlet, classname, subviews

I am having several IBOutlets of UIView; several subviews within my parent view. 
I am trying to loop over all the subviews which are UIView. 
I want to loop over all subviews that have the name of their IBOutlet starting with "view_"

Can somebody help me with this?
Question is I really want to access the name of the IBOutlet.

Here's my code for clarification:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view_player1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view_player2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view_referee1;

- (void)listSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {
    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([subviews count] == 0) return;

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        NSLog(@"my subview name is: %@", subview.class);  //?? is only giving my the type eg UIView, i want it to return view_player2

      // List the subviews of subview

       [self listSubviewsOfView:subview];
    }
}
```

How can I actually get the name of the IBOutlet of the subview and compare it if it only starts with the word "view_"

Thanks